# Wordpress shortcode always at top of page

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have the following shortcode that I am using to display a custom post on a page:

```
add_shortcode( 'page-section', 'page_section_shortcode' );
function page_section_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post-name' => 'qwerty',
        'bg-color' => 'white'
    ), $atts );
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    $post_name = $a['post-name'];
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'page_section',
        'name' => $post_name,
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div style="background-color: <?php echo $a['bg-color']; ?>" id="<?php global $post; $post_slug=$post->post_name; echo $post_slug; ?>" class="page-section">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
```

Everything is working the way I want it to, I can set the content in my custom post and use a short code to pull that content into a page.

The problem is that the content that is pulled in with the short code is always at the top of the page. Using multiple shortcodes in a row they keep their order, but any other content on the page is displayed at the bottom (below all of the shortcode content).

I have tried removing the 'echo' as suggested in another stackoverflow post but cannot seem to find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You didn't start ob_start(); at the top of start shortcode function in body.

Answer (score 5):

Replace your code to this code. This code returns generated html so it will not echo at the top of the page

```
add_shortcode( 'page-section', 'page_section_shortcode' );
function page_section_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post-name' => 'qwerty',
        'bg-color' => 'white'
    ), $atts );
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    $post_name = $a['post-name'];
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'page_section',
        'name' => $post_name,
    ) );
    $returnhtml = '';
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            global $post; 
            $returnhtml .= '<div style="background-color: '. $a['bg-color'].'" id="'.$post->post_name.'" class="page-section">';
                $returnhtml .= '<div class="row">'.get_the_content().'</div>';
            $returnhtml .= '</div>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();            
    return $returnhtml;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried this solution again, on a section with embedded shortcodes and it doesn't render the shortcode content (just a text version of it.) ' user5200704' answer to start ob_start(); has worked for me - if you put it in as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @mcneela86 : Hi can you provide screenshoot of what is appearing and what should appear? What i mean is ob_start(); may solve the issue but it is not compulsory. May be some other issue is there. Thanks for replying

Comment: @mcneela86 : You can see examples of shortcode on internet also... For example : https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-shortcodes-for-wordpress/. In this link they have not used ob_start();

Answer (score 0):

```html
function header_notification()
{   
    echo '<div><strong>Any html goes here</strong></div>';
    
}
add_action('wp_head', 'header_notification');
```